# How to insert into a table correctly using table of records and forall in pl/sql

Tags: collections, plsql, insert, bulk

I want to insert records into `MY_TABLE` using `forall`. But the no. of records dat gets inserted keeps on changing with each test run! I think it has something to do with loop counter but I am not able to figure out. Here's the code snippet.

```
DECLARE
  TYPE l_rec_type IS RECORD (
        datakey SOURCE_TABLE.datakey%TYPE,
        sourcekey SOURCE_TABLE.sourcekey%TYPE,
        DESCRIPTION SOURCE_TABLE.DESCRIPTION%TYPE,
        dimension_name SOURCE_TABLE.dimension_name%TYPE ,
        data_type   SOURCE_TABLE.data_type%TYPE

   );


  TYPE l_table_type IS TABLE OF l_rec_typeINDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
  l_table l_table_type;
  l_cntr NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR rec_dimname IN (SELECT dimension_name FROM dimension_table) LOOP
    l_cntr1 := 1
    FOR rec_source IN (SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE data_type IS NOT NULL) LOOP
      l_table(l_ctr1).datakey := rec_source.datakey;
      l_table(l_ctr1).sourcekey := rec_source.sourcekey;
      l_table(l_ctr1).DESCRIPTION := rec_source.DESCRIPTION;
      l_table(l_ctr1).dimension_name := rec_source.dimension_name;
      l_table(l_ctr1).data_type := rec_source.data_type;
      l_cntr1 := l_cntr1+1;
    END LOOP
    FORALL j IN l_table.FIRST..l_table.LAST
      INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(l_table(j).datakey,
                                  l_table(j).sourcekey,
                                  l_table(j).DESCRIPTION,
                                  l_table(j).dimension_name,
                                  l_table(j).data_type,
                                  1,
                                  SYSDATE,
                                  login_id                            
                                 );

  END LOOP;
END;
```

What am I doing wrong? Normal insert using for loop is inserting 5000 records. Another problem that I am facing is how to handle WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX and WHEN OTHERS exception using forall. In nornal for loop its easy. But I have to use FORALL for fast inserts. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code I can see that you not delete the data stored in the pl/table inside your loop and you don't have a `order by` to your query's. So if the first iteration have more data then the second you will have duplicate data.

So after initializing your `l_cntr1` var (`l_cntr1 := 1`) you must clear your pl/table:

```
l_table.delete;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes `l_table.delete` worked like a charm.. thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fixed code. Plus  [SAVE EXCEPTIONS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/tuning.htm#i49099) really saved my day!. Here is how I implemented the solution. Thank you all for your valuable time and suggestions.

```
DECLARE
      TYPE l_rec_type IS RECORD (
            datakey SOURCE_TABLE.datakey%TYPE,
            sourcekey SOURCE_TABLE.sourcekey%TYPE,
            DESCRIPTION SOURCE_TABLE.DESCRIPTION%TYPE,
            dimension_name SOURCE_TABLE.dimension_name%TYPE ,
            data_type   SOURCE_TABLE.data_type%TYPE

       );


      TYPE l_table_type IS TABLE OF l_rec_typeINDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
      l_table l_table_type;
      l_cntr NUMBER;
      ex_dml_errors EXCEPTION;
      PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(ex_dml_errors, -24381);
      login_id NUMBER := -1;
      errm VARCHAR2(512);
      err_indx NUMBER
    BEGIN
      FOR rec_dimname IN (SELECT dimension_name FROM dimension_table) LOOP
        l_cntr1 := 1;
        l_table.DELETE; -- Added
        FOR rec_source IN (SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE data_type IS NOT NULL) LOOP
          l_table(l_ctr1).datakey := rec_source.datakey;
          l_table(l_ctr1).sourcekey := rec_source.sourcekey;
          l_table(l_ctr1).DESCRIPTION := rec_source.DESCRIPTION;
          l_table(l_ctr1).dimension_name := rec_source.dimension_name;
          l_table(l_ctr1).data_type := rec_source.data_type;
          l_cntr1 := l_cntr1+1;
        END LOOP
        FORALL j IN l_table.FIRST..l_table.LAST SAVE EXCEPTIONS
          INSERT INTO my_table VALUES(l_table(j).datakey,
                                      l_table(j).sourcekey,
                                      l_table(j).DESCRIPTION,
                                      l_table(j).dimension_name,
                                      l_table(j).data_type,
                                      1,
                                      SYSDATE,
                                      login_id                            
                                     );

          END LOOP;
      END LOOP;
      EXCEPTION
        WHEN ex_dml_errors THEN
          l_error_count := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS.count;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Number of failures: ' || l_error_count);
          errm := SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE);
          err_indx := SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index
          FOR i IN 1 .. l_error_count LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Error: ' || i || 
              ' Array Index: ' || SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).error_index ||
              ' Message: ' || SQLERRM(-SQL%BULK_EXCEPTIONS(i).ERROR_CODE));
              IF errm LIKE '%unique%constraint%violated' THEN -- Insert into my_multiple_entries_tbl on duplicate value on index DATAKEY
               INSERT INTO my_multiple_entries_tbl(my_multiple_entries_tbl_seq.NEXTVAL,
                                                   l_table(err_indx).datakey,
                                                   l_table(err_indx).sourcekey,
                                                   l_table(err_indx).data_type, 
                                                   SYSDATE,
                                                   login_id   );

             ELSE -- Insert into my_other_errors_tbl on other errors
               INSERT INTO my_other_errors_tbl  (  my_other_errors_tbl_seq.NEXTVAL,
                                                   l_table(err_indx).datakey,
                                                   l_table(err_indx).sourcekey,
                                                   l_table(err_indx).data_type, 
                                                   SYSDATE,
                                                   login_id   );
             END IF; 
    END;
```

Comment: you give the correct answer but nobody seems to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Your seem to be inserting exactly the same thing multiple times - you're solely looping through the `count` of `dimension_table`, which means it can be simplified to the following, which will be faster. At the bottom is a `forall` version.

You can't use `exception when dup_val_on_index` with either version, you have to do it row by row. Judging solely by what you've posted I suspect that you can actually achieve what you're trying to do in a single query and save all this problem completely ( including dealing with duplicate values ).

```
declare

   i integer;

begin

   select count(*)
     into i
     from dimension_table;

   for j in 1 .. i loop

       insert into my_table (datakey, sourcekey, description
                            , dimension_name, someother_column
                            , some_date_column, login_id 
        select datakey, sourcekey, description, dimension_name
             , data_type, 1, sysdate, login_id -- previously missing
          from source_table 
         where data_type is not null;

   end loop;
   commit;

end;
/
```

If, however, you really want to use `forall` you can do something like this:

```
declare

   cursor c_src is
    select datakey, sourcekey, description, dimension_name
         , data_type, 1, sysdate, login_id -- previously missing
      from source_table 
     where data_type is not null;

   type t__src is table of c_src%rowtype index by binary_integer;
   t_src t__src;

   i integer;

begin

   select count(*)
     into i
     from dimension_table;

   for j in 1 .. i loop

      open c_src;
      loop

         fetch c_src bulk collect into t_src;

         forall k in t_src.first .. t_src.last
          insert into my_table (datakey, sourcekey, description
                               , dimension_name, someother_column
                               , some_date_column, login_id 
          values t_src;

      end loop;
      close c_src;

   end loop;
   commit;

end;
/
```

Comment: Hii.. I agree with you. But i need to have two for loops because of certain validation logic that goes in before I can insert into my table. The code snippet is an overview of the code design. I can't use BULK COLLECT as I am not directly selecting data from cursor. I have to initialize the table type elements. I just read about SAVE EXCEPTIONS. May be I can incorporate that.. I have no prior coding experience in it. Actually the whole design was made as Insert into MY_TABLE inside normal for loop. whenever any exception occured during exception, it was handled and the loop counter incremented

Comment: But now, normal inserts into the table is taking huge amount of time.. 8 to 9 hours. So I am trying to incorporate FORALL for Inserts.

Comment: @Arcs, you've just said everything you posted is nothing to do with your actual question! You can use `bulk collect` with what you're doing at the moment, you are selecting directly from a cursor. If you're updating values in your type you can still use `bulk collect`! What is your actual problem?

Comment: Agree with Ben. @Arcs- If you dont fetch from a cursor, how is l_table populated?

Comment: Actually, some fields are populated through the cursor and some through variables. The reason I was not getting proper count of inserts is, as pointed out by @Sérgio, the data in table type was not being deleted. `l_table.delete` worked.